# Accessing item in array returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

When iterating through an array of objects, the properties are always `undefined`. The function in my Angular component class is as such:

```
upload(): void {
    const { fileHandles, relatedThroughID }: { fileHandles: IFileHandle[], relatedThroughID: Guid } = this.form.value;

    const postData: IUploadPost = {
      base64Files: fileHandles.map(fileHandle => ({ data: fileHandle.base64, extension: fileHandle.extension })),
      relatedThroughID: relatedThroughID.toString(),
    };
  }
```

Here's a screenshot of the logged results, because I can't believe what I'm seeing - the values in the second log statement are undefined.

[image: Scfeeshot of logged code]

If I access an item by its index, the properties are also `undefined`. What in the world is happening here, and what can I do to fix it? I've never encountered a problem like this before.

Comment: I'm posting an array of objects in the body that contain base64 strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileHandle` in your map function is a reference to the array entry, not the actual array entry's `fileHandle` property.  Below is modified code.

```
upload(): void {
    const { fileHandles, relatedThroughID }: { fileHandles: IFileHandle[], relatedThroughID: Guid } = this.form.value;

    const postData: IUploadPost = {
      base64Files: fileHandles.map(x => ({ data: x.fileHandle.base64, extension: x.fileHandle.extension })),
      relatedThroughID: relatedThroughID.toString(),
    };
  }
```

Comment: I must be blind! I've simply mis-classed the form array in the .value data. Many thanks for the extra set of eyes, I appreciate it!